# Restore Back In Time From Ubuntu To Debian

Tags: debian, ubuntu, backup, backintime

I used Back In Time (BIT) to back up my data to an external USB drive on Ubuntu 12.04. After problems with Ubuntu I made a fresh install of Debian 8.3. In Debian I have installed BIT and can see the USB drive. However, BIT cannot see the old snapshots.

I had thought I would be able to restore on the new install.

Answer (score 1):

I already told you this via mail but I'll add it here, too so others will find it in future.

This is [from our new FAQ](https://github.com/bit-team/backintime/wiki/FAQ#back-in-time-doesn-t-find-my-old-snapshots-on-my-new-computer):

---

Back In Time prior to version 1.1.0 had an option called
`Auto Host/User/Profile ID` (hidden under `General > Advanced`) which will
always use the current host- and username for the full snapshot path.
While (re-)installing your Computer you probably chose a different host- or
username than on your old machine. With `Auto Host/User/Profile ID` activated
Back In Time now try to find your Snapshots under the new host- and username
underneath the `/path/to/backintime/` path.

The `Auto Host/User/Profile ID` option is gone in version 1.1.0 and above.
It was totaly confusing and didn't add any good.

You have three options to fix this:

- Disable `Auto Host/User/Profile ID` and change `Host` and `User` to match
  your old machine. [image: Auto Host/User/Profile ID option hidden under General > Advanced]
- Rename the Snapshot path
  `/path/to/backintime/OLDHOSTNAME/OLDUSERNAME/profile_id` to match your new
  host- and username.
- Upgrade to a more recent version of Back In Time (1.1.0 or above).
  The `Auto Host/User/Profile ID` option is gone and it also comes with
  an assistant to restore the config from an old Snapshot on first start.